# Algorithms - can I use built-in utility functions for online coding interviews and challenges?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a number of algorithm based coding interviews (coderpad.io) and online challenges like hackerrank coming up in Objective-c. I do not do these often and want to understand if I'm allowed to use built in sorting, searching and compare functions like below to solve algorithmic questions.

**During a coding interview, do I have to pretend like the Objective-c has no sorting, reversing and other utilities?**

Or is everything fair game, just get the solution out?

If there's a better medium to ask this question, please tell me where to post this.

From here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Objective-C

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Node : NSObject {
@public
  id val;
  Node *back;
}
@end

@implementation Node
@end

@interface NSArray (LIS)
- (NSArray *)longestIncreasingSubsequenceWithComparator:(NSComparator)comparator;
@end

@implementation NSArray (LIS)
- (NSArray *)longestIncreasingSubsequenceWithComparator:(NSComparator)comparator {
  NSMutableArray *pileTops = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  // sort into piles
  for (id x in self) {
    Node *node = [[Node alloc] init];
    node->val = x;
    int i = [pileTops indexOfObject:node
                      inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [pileTops count])
                            options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex|NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual
                    usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Node *node1, Node *node2) {
                      return comparator(node1->val, node2->val);
                    }];
    if (i != 0)
      node->back = pileTops[i-1];
    pileTops[i] = node;
  }

  // follow pointers from last node
  NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (Node *node = [pileTops lastObject]; node; node = node->back)
    [result addObject:node->val];
  return [[result reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    for (NSArray *d in @[@[@3, @2, @6, @4, @5, @1],
         @[@0, @8, @4, @12, @2, @10, @6, @14, @1, @9, @5, @13, @3, @11, @7, @15]])
      NSLog(@"an L.I.S. of %@ is %@", d,
            [d longestIncreasingSubsequenceWithComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2];
      }]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During a coding interview, you can always ask if you can use such-and-such a function from the library, but generally you can as long as that doesn't save you from actually having to solve the problem.

If you're asked to implement a sort, for example, you shouldn't do it by calling the library sort.  If you're asked to implement a class that accomplishes some task, then you shouldn't do it by delegating to a class that's already provided to perform that task.

The above implementation of patience sorting would generally be fine, since none of the library functions called is specifically related to the longest-increasing-subsequence problem.

In a coding interview, you should really be thinking of this the other way around: **The question is an opportunity to demonstrate your skills.  What do you want to show off?**

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the types of problems typically posed *could be* solved using built in sorting, searching, etc. utility functions, but using them probably won't be the most efficient approach. For example, selecting the top k items from an unordered list is trivially solved by sorting and then taking the first k items. But that is not the optimum solution. In an interview, the interviewer will probably ask you to provide an alternate solution. On the test sites, your code will probably exceed the time limit.

For interviews, it's a good idea to discuss your proposed solution with the interviewer. As somebody else said, *ask* the interviewer if it's okay to use built-in methods. Interview questions are often intentionally ambiguous to elicit such conversations. Interviewers are interested in your technical prowess, but also interested in seeing how you approach a problem. That includes asking for clarification if requirements are not clear.